# Linearity Assumption in OLS with Dummy Variables

Tags: regression, least-squares, nonlinear-regression, categorical-encoding

Let's say that I have a continuous response variable and have constructed a regression model with multiple predictors. Most of my predictors are continuous but I have one which is a dummy variable. How do I determine whether the ols assumption of linearity is met or violated? And if the linearity assumption is violated, how would I go about transforming the dummy variable?

Comment: A dummy variable takes values of either 0 or 1. How might it exhibit a non-linear relation to the response?

Comment: Linearity does not mean that the independent variables have to be continuous; it merely means the response is a linear function of whatever values the independent variables happen to take on, as in, for example, the linear function $3x$, which makes no assumptions about $x$.

Comment: so in the following link, where the author claims that "linear regression needs the relationship between the independent and dependent variables to be linear"....that's wrong? or am I thinking about relationship wrong by assuming it's meaning a 'scatterplot' relationship. http://www.statisticssolutions.com/academic-solutions/resources/directory-of-statistical-analyses/assumptions-of-linear-regression/

Comment: @amathew: I was starting to list the errors at that link, but there are too many - just forget about it & read something else.

Comment: I see that error mentioned over and over at so many places. So linearity is not about the relationship, just that 'the linear function makes no assumption about x," meaning that we don't make any transformations to x. Of course, there are times when we can transform data (3x^2) and use that within a linear model. The question then becomes, when is a 'linear model' inadaquete and when is it appropriate to use data transformation or a nonlinear model.

Comment: @Scortchi If there were only a few errors on that page we should be generous in our assessment, because anyone who writes about stats is bound to make some mistakes. However, these errors seem like fundamental misconceptions. I am pleased that there are already good answers on CV dealing with them all. The writer claims he "[has gained statistical and mythological experience](http://www.dissertationwritingservices.info/statisticssolutions-com-review/)" in helping people write their dissertations. As always on the Web, *caveat lector,* especially when mixing mythology and stats. :-)

Comment: @whuber: Fundamental mythconceptions, perhaps.

Comment: @whuber The use of that quoted phrase would be enough to make me wary of the rest of what they said. Even before reading the particulars in this case, statements of such a flavor are usually associated with deep misunderstandings.

Answer (score 5):

It's time this question had an answer.

> I have a continuous response variable and a regression model with multiple predictors.
>   Most of my predictors are continuous

The continuity or otherwise of a predictor makes no no difference; a relationship only need be linear over the domain where it's defined, for it to be linear.

> How do I determine whether the ols assumption of linearity is met or violated?

With a 0/1 predictor ($d$ say) there are only two possibilities:

$E(Y|d=0,\underline{x})=E(Y|d=1,\underline{x})$ or

$E(Y|d=0,\underline{x})\neq E(Y|d=1,\underline{x})$

(where $\underline{x}$ is all the other predictors)

In either case, linearity is satisfied, since the population coefficient is the difference in expected values in either case.

It is, however, possible that the size of the coefficient depends on the values of the other parameters (i.e. interactions between other predictors and $d$ may exist).

> And if the linearity assumption is violated, how would I go about transforming the dummy variable?

The (conditional) linearity of $y$ in terms of $d$ is automatically satisfied - 
fortunately, because we can't gain anything substantive here by attempting to transform a dummy.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the excellent answer by [Glen_b](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/805/glen-b), it is worth noting that adding a categorical variable into a regression *cannot cause problems with the linearity assumption in and of itself*.  If there is an issue of non-linearity in the model it will be due to some underlying relationship that is not captured by the specified model form, but the inclusion of a categorical variable cannot cause this problem.

To see this more clearly, consider a regression with an arbitrary categorical variable $h = 1,...,k$ with $k \geqslant 2$ possible outcomes, and one or more other terms encapsulated by $\mathbf{x}.$  The categorical variable is represented in a regression by $k-1$ indicator variables for the categories (with one base category).  So the relevant terms in the model will look like this:

$$\mathbb{E}(Y_i|\mathbf{x},\mathbf{h}) = \beta_0 + \sum_{\ell=1}^{k-1} \beta_\ell \cdot \mathbb{I}(h_i = \ell) + \text{Other terms for } x_i.$$

The linearity assumption in regression requires that the regression equation be linear *with respect to the coefficient parameters*.  The presence of the categorical variable $h$ in the regression adds the parameters $\beta_1,...\beta_{k-1}$ which apply across categories.  Each individual indicator term simply adds a term for the difference in conditional expectation based on whether the categorical variable is in that category or not.  The addition of such terms cannot constitute non-linearity.